# Gompertz function in Ruby

Tags: ruby, math

I am not a mathematician, but I'm trying to generate a sequence of numbers that will, when plotted, produce a Gompertz curve starting at x=0. I would like to be able to specify the asymptote and the length of this curve

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_function) says the formula is:

> y(t)=ae^{be^{ct}}
>
> where a is the upper asymptote
>
> b,c are negative numbers
>
> b sets the displacement along the x axis (translates the graph to the left or right)
>
> c sets the growth rate (y scaling)
>
> e is Euler's Number (e = 2.71828...)

This is what I've got,

```
def gompertz(asymptote, length)
  seq = (0..length) # these will be my y values
  seq.map do |t|  
    asymptote * Math::E ** # ae to the power of...
      (-1 * Math::E) ** # be, to the power of...
      (t * -1) # ct
  end
end
```

But when I put in the figures from the wikipedia illustrations( asymptote = 1, b = -4, c = -2 ), and a length of 10 I get this:

```
gompertz(1, 10)
=> [2.718281828459045, 1.0184843989442722, 1.0003355189017822, 1.0000061442312291,     1.000000112535181, 1.0000000020611537, 1.0000000000377514, 1.0000000000006914, 1.0000000000000127, 1.0000000000000002, 1.0]
```

Obv, the first plot is above the asymptote! I'm getting something seriously wrong here. Can you help?

Comment: Please make the formula more clear. Are the `ae` and `be` raised, or just `e`?

Comment: I mean, is it `(ae)^ ( (be)^ (ct) )` or `a* (e^ (b* (e^ (ct))))`?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, thanks - it turns out that was exactly my problem, which aurel pointed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are exponentiating `b` to the power (t * -1). What you want is

```
b * (Math::E ** (t * -1) )
```

instead of

```
(b * Math::E ** (t * -1) )
```